Can I use this old LG as an Android TV?
I have an old monitor that is still working ok (LG W2361V).
Is it possible to make it into a TV by using an Android box or is it too old for that? What about the sound?

Doubtful without additional hardware as based on: https://www.lg.com/ca_en/monitors/fhd-qhd/w2361v-pf/ it is just a monitor without HDMI-CEC & Audio support thru the HDMI connector. You would need a extractor/converter box to take the output from a Android TV device to get the audio signal out. Searching on "turn monitor to TV" should give you options. To my knowledge Android TV box devices can't normally split audio to Bluetooth headphones or does so with lag due to HDMI delays but YMMV.

@MorrisonChang: So the movie could play fine but the only issue is the audio?

Yes, I believe so. I recall connecting an old Android/Google TV box to a monitor once, it worked but as there was no speaker output on the monitor or the box, no audio could be heard.

@MorrisonChang: Something like this? https://www.amazon.com/Android-Netflix-Certified-Support-Assistant/dp/B09FDM2MSX/  This mentions audio if I undestand correctly

Honestly I don't know if that particular device will handle non-HDMI audio with HDMI video stream correctly. Do note that hardware recommendations are off-topic here. However you can ask on the seller product page questions and hopefully either confirm or deny that the setup/configuration you want will work. Good luck.

@MorrisonChang: So I should be looking for a device that handles HDMI video and non HDMI audio? Why is that?

I was more concerned about possible general HDMI audio sync problems but that would depend upon what player/app you are using and how the audio is connected to the box as the monitor doesn't have HDMI audio/HDMI-ARC. Ideally the box you linked to has system level audio sync adjustment so audio can be synchronized.
